# Software Center doesn't start after installing an application

Tags: 12.04, software-center

*Translated using Google Translate:*

I have a problem on my PC. After installation of an application, the software center crashes. When I run it in a terminal, the following messages posters:

```
andriajozy@andrejose:~$ software-center
WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to: /tmp/keyring-xH50MG/pkcs11: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
2013-02-20 17:34:03,973 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/importer.py', 51, 'find_module')'
2013-02-20 17:34:03,973 - root - ERROR - Could not find any typelib for Gst
2013-02-20 17:34:04,053 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2013-02-20 17:34:04,059 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True
2013-02-20 17:34:04,144 - softwarecenter.region - WARNING - failed to use geoclue: 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Master was not provided by any .service files'
2013-02-20 17:34:04,610 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2013-02-20 17:34:04,846 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - show_available_packages: search_text is '', app is None.
```

What can I do in order to remedy this? I uninstalled the application recently added in vain. I tried also to remove and reinstall software-center but it does not solve the problem.

Can someone help me? Thank you for your help. Running Ubuntu 12.04 AMD64 I

Answer (score 0):

Welcome my dear french friend,

this is a community project that's meant to be helpful for all sorts of people. To make that possible it's advised to post things in english: "the lingua franca" of our nice little planet.

Je vous en prie de poser votre question en anglais. Si on trouve une solution a votre probleme elle devient utile uniquement pour les francophones. Je vous demande donc de faire un effort et de poser votre question dans une langue pratique. La langue francaise est tres belle, mais absolument provenciale et ridicule dans le contexte de l'internet.

essayer/ please try:

```
cd ~/.cache
```

ensuite / then:

```
rm -r software-center
```

finalement/ finally:

```
cd; software-center
```